# Finding a plane in $\mathbb{R}^3$ given five points

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-programming

I have multiple vertices that I need to create a plane out of. What is a formula/method for having a plane that contains 5 points?

I believe I could use just 3 and the other two will be included

Comment: but which of the three? what if you have $5 \choose 5$ planes?

Answer (score 2):

Given three points $u$, $v$, $w$, form $u-v$ and $u-w$.  Then take the cross product of $u-v$ and $u-w$ to get a vector normal to the plane.  Suppose that $u=(u_1,u_2,u_3)$ and the normal vector is $(a,b,c)$.  Then the equation for the plane will be
$$
a(x-u_1)+b(y-u_2)+c(z-u_3)=0.
$$